# select data that belongs to category

Tags: sql, dql

I have three tables like this:

table **player**:
id, name

table **matchevent**:
id, player_id, eventcategory_id, description

table **eventcategory**:
id, name

Relations are: 
*player : matchevent - 1:N
matchevent : eventcategory - N:1*

In table player I have football player names and in eventcategory events, like yellow card, substitution etc. In table matchevent I store player events which belongs to some category.

And now I want to retrieve COUNT of events that all players have. For example:

- first player has COUNT of yellow cards 0, substitution 0 and goals 0
- second player has 1 yellow card, 0 substitution and 2 goals
- third player have 0 yellow cards, 0 substitution 0 goals
- etc

How can I do that in DQL? I tried LEFT JOIN and IN, but it doesn't work. It selects only players with events, not all players.

```
->createQuery('SELECT p, i
               FROM MyBundle:player p 
               LEFT JOIN p.matchevent i
               WHERE i.eventcategory IN (:eventcategory)
               ORDER BY p.player ASC
               ')
->setParameters(array(
               'eventcategory' => $eventcategory,
))
```

Comment: I think you mean `COUNT` rather then `SUM`

Comment: Count, of course. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use a right join that should force it to return all players even if they don't have events.

```
'SELECT p, i
       FROM MyBundle:player p 
       RIGHT JOIN p.matchevent i
       WHERE i.eventcategory IN (:eventcategory)
       ORDER BY p.player ASC
       ')
```